# document.write to php variable

Tags: php, variables, document.write

I have this javascript

```
document.write(img)
```

The value of the "img" is something like:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMYAAADGCAYAAACJm/9dAAAgAEl ect.."
```

Now I want that "img" to be like a PHP variable. Is that possible?

Comment: passing it via ajax without reloading the page or via post if you can reload the page. PHP is SERVER SIDE and JS is CLIENT SIDE so...

Comment: Hi Lelio,

How? can you show me? just some ideas

Comment: looking at your comments also to other answers please: rephrase your question to explain what is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of this - completely untested btw.

```
$img='data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( file_get_contents('/path/to/image.png') );
echo "var img='{$img}';";
```

Comment: hmm, doesn't work, what i need is to pass the value of that "img" to php. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html5:

```
<canvas id="img"></canvas>

<script>
   var canvas = document.getElementById("img");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   var image = new Image();
   image.onload = function() {
       ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
   };
    image.src = "<?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.
    base64_encode( file_get_contents('/path/to/image.png') ); ?>"; //from RamRaider Answer

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
thanks, but i still haven't save it yet so i think there's no need to get the path yet, what i did is to display the "img" and hoping to pass it to PHP variable then create a script to upload it into server.

Comment: oh you mean upload to server?

Comment: yep, after passing it to php variable, then the next step for me is to create script to upload it to server.

Comment: "passing to php variable", means uploading it, you can't pass variable from javascript to php without doing any post\get request

Comment: you mean like $_GET['img']?

Comment: yes, this is why your question is confusing because of writing document.write

Comment: How would i use $_GET['img'] in the below javascript.

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(img);
</script>